# Delete every other items leaving the selected ones from the list of files at a shot

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a file with many other unwanted items in it i want to delete them all automatically leaving behind the data needed

I have around 100 of cells i need only the cell name and all the pin and direction for those 100 cells and delete every other item (41437 no of lines in lib file)

```
grep -A 41435 'cell' lib | grep -iE '(cell|pin|direction)'
```

output

```
cell( FVOXY_O_W11X ) {                                                                                                                                   
        pa_p ( vcc ) {                                                                                                                                        
          direction : input;                                                                                                                                    
        pb_p ( vss ) {                                                                                                                                        
          direction : input;                                                                                                                                    
  is_macro_cell : true;                                                                                                                                         
pin(measure) {                                                                                                                                          
        related_p_pin : x ;                                                                                                                               
        related_g_pin : y ;                                                                                                                              
        direction : inout ;                                                                                                                                     
        original :measure;                                                                                                                         
} /* end of pin measure */                                                                                                                              
pin(pass) {                                                                                                                                                   
        related_p_pin : x ;                                                                                                                               
        related_g_pin :y ;                                                                                                                              
        direction : input ;                                                                                                                                     
        original : pass;                                                                                                                                  
} /* end of pin pass */
```

what I need

```
cell( FOVIO_NOM_D2DSYNC8X )

pin(measure)
 direction : inout 

pin(pass)
direction : input
```

Like such i have around 100 cell I want only the cell name and all the pin and direction of that cell can any one tell me how can

Comment: Using `(^cell|^pin|direction)'` almost provides the correct answer. Perhaps good enough?

Comment: why `direction` is missed under `cell` in your output?

Comment: what do you mean by direction

Comment: o its cell [cell( FVOXY_O_W11X ) ]at the output also by mistake

Comment: If you want help writing a tool to parse a file, you need to show us that file, not just the output you get from trying to parse the file and the desired output. [edit] your question to include the sample input that would produce your posted output. Also explain your requirements better. It's not clear at all what kind of input file could produce the output you say you get given  the command you are running, nor is it clear why the output you say is expected would be the expected output given your description of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '/^cell/; /^pin/{print; p=1} p && /direction/{print; p=0}' file
```

will give you the lines

```
cell( FVOXY_O_W11X ) {                                                                                                                                   
pin(measure) {                                                                                                                                          
        direction : inout ;                                                                                                                                     
pin(pass) {                                                                                                                                                   
        direction : input ;
```

you can do some filtering before printing to get rid of the unwanted chars.

**Explanation**

> `/^cell/;` print lines that start with "cell"
>
> `/^pin/{print; p=1}` print lines that start with "pin" and set variable *p* so we know we're in "pin" context
>
> `p && /direction/{print; p=0}` if we're in "pin" context print lines that have "direction" and reset *p* to get out from current "pin" context.

Comment: can you tell me what for this P is used and what do you mean by p=1 and p=0